# Multiple threads working on the same object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a POJO BusStop which has a name of the bus stop and how many passengers are there.

```
public class BusStop{
    private String name;
    private Integer passengers;
    //setters getters constructor
    public void removePassengers(Integer i){
        synchronized(passengers){
             this.passengers = this.passengers - i; // right now I allow them to go below zero for the sake of just testing threads;
        }
    }

    public void increasePassengers(Integer i){
        synchronized(passengers){
             this.passengers = this.passengers + i;
        }
    }
}
```

And an object BusRide which contains a source BusStop, a destination BusStop and how many passengers are currently in that ride.

```
public class BusRide implements Runnable{

    private BusStop source;
    private BusStop destination
    private Integer passengers;

    public BusRide(BusStop src, BusStop dest){
        this.source = src;
        this.destination = dest;
    }
    //setters getters

    @Override
    public void run(){
        setPassengers(15);
        this.source.removePassengers(15);
        setPassengers(0);
        this.destination.increasePassengers(15);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
            BusStop a = new BusStop("Bus-stop 1", 50);
            BusStop b = new BusStop("Bus-stop 2", 45);
            BusStop c = new BusStop("Bus-stop 3", 62);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new BusRide(a,b));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new BusRide(a,c));
    }

}
```

In my main class I want to create 2 threads of BusRide, which are going to take a random number of passengers from the source BusStop to the destination BusStop. But I want the BusRide threads to take passengers from the object that I gave them, but instead they have their own instances of a BusStop object. So how do I make the two threads operate on the same BusStop object that I've given them?

Comment: I don't figure out your issue. Both `BusRide`s still impact the same instance of `BusStop` referenced by `a`. Isn't what you expect?

Comment: By the way, why to make this method private? `private void removePassengers(Integer i)` ? Your whole code doesn't compile.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was an accident, it should be public. But my problem is it still doesn't work, for some reason the threads don't change the BusStop passengers count. As in the threads can't change the given objects field.

Comment: Remove all lines in your run method except this.sources.removedPassengers(15). You will notice the impact. Your passengers amount at source should end up to 20.

Comment: And you should really not change object that you use for locking. Indeed, you lock on passengers and change it's variable. Try put the lock on the whole method (the `this` object) in this simple case.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void removePassengers(Integer i){
    synchronized(passengers){
         this.passengers = this.passengers - i; // right now I allow them to go below zero for the sake of just testing threads;
    }
}

public void increasePassengers(Integer i){
    synchronized(passengers){
         this.passengers = this.passengers + i;
    }
}
```

The above is wrong. It should be

```
public synchronized void removePassengers(Integer i){
    this.passengers = this.passengers - i; // right now I allow them to go below zero for the sake of just testing threads;
}

public synchronized void increasePassengers(Integer i){
    this.passengers = this.passengers + i;
}
```

Indeed, you're synchronizing on an passengers, but assign passengers to another value inside the synchronized block, essentially making it possible for two threads to invoke the methods at the same time. Always make a variable `final` if you use it as a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Threads were not started.

/**
 * 
 */
package com.philips.webcms.foundation.catalog.products.utils.test;

/**
 * @author AV262488
 */
public class ThreadTest
{

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BusStop a = new BusStop("Bus-stop 1", 50);
    BusStop b = new BusStop("Bus-stop 2", 45);
    BusStop c = new BusStop("Bus-stop 3", 62);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new BusRide(a, b));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new BusRide(a, c));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    System.out.println(a.getPassengers());

}
```

}